# Is this an effective way to make changes to a deployed Flask app?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, nginx, flask, github

I have deployed my first website on an Ubuntu 20.04 server using Nginx and Gunicorn and I am wondering what would be the best way for me to keep this website up to date with the changes to the GitHub repository?

Currently, I am updating by:

ssh into server

pulling the latest changes from the GitHub repo

entering GitHub username and Personal Access Token

then restarting nginx - `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.

Is there a less manual way to make updates?

Is there a simpler, quicker and more effective way I could merge changes to a small Flask app?

Is there best practice for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting NGINX does not help at all. You need to restart gunicorn after you pulled in code changes.

Other than that your way of deploying changes is certainly ok.

If you want automatic deployments, you can use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or [batou](https://batou.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or similar tools. But beware, you need to invest quite some time to learn those tools.

Comment: Yikes, it does for me. After I have restarted Nginx then all of the latest changes are live. Ok, thanks for the suggestions and the warnigns, I will look into those if I am ever managing multiple websites.

Comment: "Other than that your way of deploying changes is certainly ok." - I am glad that you said this. I have just discovered that changes to the Python code are not deployed via Nginx, which makes sense. I just restarted Supervisor. If you hadn't mentioned that it might have taken me a while to wonder what is going on!

Comment: Well, you never mentioned supervisor before  Probably supervisor is running gunicorn which runs your Flask application. So all good. If you are OK with my answer, I'd appreciate an upvote or that you accept it. Thank you!